# pycassa create column family exception when seen with cassandra-cli

Tags: python, pycassa, cassandra-2.0

as I am new to Cassandra. I want to create a column family using pycassa API. I have created a column family by using the following code:

```
validators = {'full_name': UTF8_TYPE,
          'email': UTF8_TYPE,
          'state': UTF8_TYPE,
          'gender': UTF8_TYPE,
          'birth_year': LONG_TYPE}

sys.create_column_family('TestKeyspace', 'TestCF', super=False,
          comparator_type=UTF8_TYPE,
          key_validation_class=UTF8_TYPE, 
          column_validation_classes=validators)
```

The python script is running fine without any exceptions. But when I check this column family using cassandra-cli. I got the follwing exception:

```
UnavailableException()
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result$get_range_slices_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:17439)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result$get_range_slices_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:17397)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result.read(Cassandra.java:17323)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:802)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:786)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeList(CliClient.java:1520)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:285)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:201)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:331)
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. Does anyone have working code for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create the Keyspace and what are the replication settings for it?  `UnavailableException` means that there aren't enough live replicas to respond to the query.  My guess is that you either accidentally set the replication factor too high, or you're using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` and the datacenter names in the replication settings don't match the actual datacenter names for your nodes.

Comment: No, my replication factor is 1 and I am using SIMPLE Strategy. Here is code snippet:
`sys.create_keyspace('db5', SIMPLE_STRATEGY, {'replication_factor': '1'})`

Comment: Well in that case, do you have more than one node or any down nodes?  Run `nodetool status` on each node to see if any of them think another node is down.

Comment: Yes, I have a three node cluster and the other two nodes were down. So, I cleanup the dead nodes &  now I can see the data in cassandra-cli(without any exception) which I have inserted using pycassa API. Thank you very much Sir. Keep up the good work.